# Matlab - multiple variables normalized histogram?

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalize

I'm working on MATLAB, where I have a vector which I need to split into two classes and then get a histogram of both resulting vectors (which have different sizes). The values represent height records so the interval is about 140-185.
How can I get a normalized histogram of both resulting vectors in different colors. I was able to get both normalized vectors in the same colour (which is indistiguible) and and also a histogram with different colours but not not normalized...

I hope you understand my question and will be able to help me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show your code so that we can suggest improvements

Comment: well, the data can either be on a matrix (each collumn representing one of the classes, with NaN on the positions without value - each position has only one value per class) or on two separate vectors (of different sizes).
My first attempt has just using hist(Matrix), which generates an histogram with the two classes colour-separated, but the data isn't normalized.
To achieve normalized histograms I used this function http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22802-normalized-histogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
matrix = [155+10*randn(2000,1) 165+10*randn(2000,1)];
matrix(1:1100,1) = NaN;
matrix(1101:2000,2) = NaN;  %// example data

[y x] = hist(matrix, 15); %// 15 is desired number of bins
y = bsxfun(@rdivide, y, sum(y)) / (x(2)-x(1)); %// normalize to area 1
bar(x,y) %// plots each column of y vs x. Automatically uses different colors
```

[image]